# Synonymize "google-chrome-to-phone" and "chrome-to-phone"

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Title basically says it. [google-chrome-to-phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-to-phone) and [chrome-to-phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-to-phone) should probably be synonymized somehow. I'd personally say I have no real opinion either way, though [chrome-to-phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-to-phone) seems clear to me without the leading "google" at the front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made [google-chrome-to-phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-to-phone) the master to be consistent with our other tags.

Comment: Meh. That's an awfully long tag, and it's not like "Chrome to Phone" needs to be disambiguated.